# Why no MVC 4 project template in Visual Studio 2010 when MVC 4 & tools are installed?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

When I create a new web project in Visual Studio 2010, I don't see an option for a MVC 4 web project. I have MVC 4 (preview) and VS2010 MVC 4 tools installed. I see ones for MVC2 & MVC3.

Comment: Check the `Target Framework` dropdown

Comment: Check for what? I tried 4, 4.01 and June CTP and they didn't show it. I don't have 4.5. Is that needed?

Comment: I don't know; I haven't tried the preview.

Answer (score 7):

You can't create an MVC 4 web site nor a .Net 3.5 Web Application.

You can go

**File -> New -> Project -> Select .Net Framework 4 -> ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application**

Answer (score 1):

[This Update Link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30683) will download the setup for ASP.NET MVC 4 for VS 2010 SP1.